# Reading Lines from Two files in the appropriate order using Multi threading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, file-handling

Suppose I have two files name A and B. If,

**File A contains:**

Hi.

How are you?

**File B contains:**

My name is Ayush.

I'm doing Great.

**Output:**

HI.

My name is Ayush.

How are you?

I'm doing Great.

As I know we can only request the JVM and if the other thread in the queue is not ready the next thread is executed again. I have tried using flags and set Priority, but I always get the random output. Sometimes the line from second file B is read first and sometimes from the file A. It disturbs the order in which I want an answer.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
class Synchronization{
    public void readFromFile(Scanner sc) throws Exception{
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
     }
  }

class SynchronizedThreads extends Thread{

    @Override
    public void run(){
        Scanner sc;

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("A")){
            try{
                sc = new Scanner(new File("FirstFile.txt"));
                object.readFromFile(sc);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }else if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("B")){
            try{
                sc = new Scanner(new File("SecondFile.txt"));
                object.readFromFile(sc);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Synchronization object = new Synchronization();
      SynchronizedThreads t1 = new SynchronizedThreads(object);
      SynchronizedThreads t2 = new SynchronizedThreads(object);
      //SynchronizedThreads t = new SynchronizedThreads(object);
      t1.setName("A");
      t2.setName("B");
      //t.setName("Temp");
      //t.start();
      //t1.setPriority(10);
      //t2.setPriority(5);
      t1.start();
      t2.start();
   }
}
```

**Second Code**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class ConcurrencyControl extends Thread{

    volatile static boolean sema = true;
    private String pathForFirstFile = "FirstFile.txt";
    private String pathForSecondFile = "SecondFile.txt";

    @Override//run() Method
    public void run(){
        String  threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        if(threadName.equals("FirstFile")){
            try{
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(pathForFirstFile));
                if(sema == true){ 
                    while(sc.hasNextLine() /*&& sema == true*/){
                        System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
                        sema = false;
                        sleep(500);
                    }
                }else{
                    sleep(500);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        else if(threadName.equals("SecondFile")){
            try{
                Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(new File(pathForSecondFile));
                if(sema == false){
                    while(sc1.hasNextLine() /*&& sema == false*/){
                        System.out.println(sc1.nextLine());
                        sema = true;
                        sleep(500);
                    }
                }else{
                    sleep(500);
                }
            }catch(Exception ex){
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ConcurrencyControl threadOne = new ConcurrencyControl();
        threadOne.setName("FirstFile");
        ConcurrencyControl threadSecond = new ConcurrencyControl();
        threadSecond.setName("SecondFile");
        threadOne.start();
        threadSecond.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to do the synchronization? As I can see you start reading the files at the same time, and output the contents immediately, without waiting for anything (except that half second sleep, but that's unconditional).

Comment: I'm no expert in this but it looks like producer/consumer with 2 producers giving to one consumer. The consumer will need to control the order of things

Comment: @skandigraun The class only has a method which I call In the SynchronizedThreads. Actually, I need a sleep method over there because, if thread A reads the first line from the First File it should wait for the thread B to read the first line from the Second File, and order should be maintained.

Comment: I kind of see the idea, but this method will be always random and unreliable, as it relies on luck. You could introduce a lock or flag that would indicate when can a file be read. When A finished with a line, it sets the flag to "B_can_read", and goes to sleep, waiting until the flag is "A_can_read". B does the same: if the flag is "B_can_read", it reads, and sets the flag to "A_can_read", then goes to sleep waiting its turn. Or something along the lines, as an example.

Comment: I have tried using this Logic. I'm editing and posting the second code, check if you can help there. Thanks @skandigraun

Comment: Almost - put the sema check inside the while loop, not outside. At this moment it is checked only once, but it should be verified before every line read.

Comment: Oh thanks @skandigraun, it worked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels "_I'm no expert_" - I'm not so sure.

Comment: strongly recommend having a look at the [java.util.concurrent package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-frame.html) - some class there should fit, e.g. `CyclicBarrier`, `Semaphore` or even a `Lock` (in java.util.concurrent.locks)

Answer (score -2):

Have a flag say `isATurn`. Initially set `isATurn` to `true`. Create two threads call in the order. Put your conditional statements inside a `synchronized` block to check for the turns and process it accordingly. You have to invert the flag everytime you process the file.

```
public void processA() {
   while (!isATurn); //wait till processB method to invert the flag
   synchronized(this) {
       processNow();
       isATurn = !isATurn;  
   }
}
```

Implement `processB` method in the same manner.

Edit: `Thread.sleep()` is slightly low level and achieving thread safety using that is more difficult. Java provides us with `synchronized` keyword to deal with these problems in a more elegant way.

Edit: Moved busy waiting outside the `synchronized` block to avoid poor CPU utilization.

Comment: `while (!isATurn)` - this is called a [spinlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock). It's good for two things - 1) very low latency programming, 2) creating a fan heater. One thing to bear in either of those options is that you have ramped a thread to 100% and nothing else can use it. This is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: I agree @BoristheSpider The question itself imposes some order. If the tasks are independent then we can make the CPU utilization better with threads. I believe this inherent order imposition will always to lead to poor CPU utilization. Suggestions are welcome from you about how to make this efficient.

Comment: Incorrect. For example, using `wait()`, `notify()` will allow the waiting thread to be returned to the scheduler. If you don't know how to write concurrent code, please don't post answers.